# how to set social icons to product / post template (Auros theme)?

Tags: posts, templates, social-sharing, social-connect

After installation of the Auros theme, the social share icons are unfortunately not loaded in the product and the post template.

It should be loaded like this via the template:
[image: https://preview.themeforest.net/item/auros-furniture-elementor-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/22873765?_ga=2.254785614.715446228.1643105094-1698967205.1639652675]

Do you have any idea what do I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the sharing icons part of the theme or are you adding them with another plugin or widget? You should ask the Auros theme authors please - they'll know their theme better than us, and since you bought the theme they should support you.

Comment: Unfortunately the support is only avaible for 1 year and I bought it before :/

Answer (score 1):

Those icons are from Font Awesome as it can be seen in the page source. [image]

You should have this tag or something that looks like this somewhere right after the  opening tag:

```
<link data-minify="1" rel="stylesheet" id="font-awesome-css" href="https://demo2wpopal.b-cdn.net/auros/wp-content/cache/min/1/auros/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1633574147" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Try adding it either by editing the theme file directly or through some kind of plugin.

This should fix the problem, though this shouldn't occur at all. I'm guessing you have some kind of optimizer plugin enabled that concats and minimizes html/css/js and in the process messes with your theme.

Edit: I'm taking the info from the [theme's demo](https://preview.themeforest.net/item/auros-furniture-elementor-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/22873765), as you didn't link your site or given additional details, so based on your theme version and other factors *it's possible* that it's a bit different on your site.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunalety it is not a problem of font-awesome library not loaded correctly. I think the theme supposed to modify the woocomerce products template as well as the blog post single template to add these fields. And this did not happen

Comment: Does it load the <a> and <i> tags?

Comment: no, unfortunately it does not render the whole <div class="pbr-social-share">Share on: ... tag

Comment: Did you add the links in any way in admin?

Comment: yes I tried, and unfortunately it does not help

Comment: If all the settable options are set correctly on the admin page it could be that the hooks don't have the correct priority, some other plugin might clash with the theme, but without further information, it's hard to say.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not even shown after  a fresh clean install of the theme